# In math notation, how to indicate that one number is supposed to be appended/prepended to (or inserted in) another number as a whole?

Tags: notation

I don't know if there exists a special, separate term for this operation in mathematics (maybe **"to ascribe"**?), but here is an example. Let's say I have a variable $m=2$ and I want to write it at the end of number $1$ in order to get another variable $n$. How to indicate this intention? I should write something like $n=1\{<m>\}=12$. That is, if $m=20$, then $n=120$, and so on... Is there a professional notation for this in math?

Comment: When we talk about "words" or "strings" we refer to this operation as [concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation_%28mathematics%29).  I have heard people refer to "concatenating numbers" as well.  The wiki-math page suggests the notation $a\| b$.  E.g. $57\| 123 = 57123$.

Comment: Some people use notation $\overline{xy}$ to denote number $10x+y$.

Comment: @JMoravitz: thank you. But how to indicate that a number should be inserted in the middle of another number? $n = 1||m||9$ (to get 129, from the above example)?

Comment: I don't think there's a convention.  I think if use simply include a sentence "I will use the convention of a string of variables to represent the number with those variable as digits.  I will intersperse actual digits amid variable to represent known digits."  Then just write n = 1m9.

Comment: @cr001: yes, yes, I also remember that I've seen the overbar/overline in some book for a similar operation. But when I checked [wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_%28symbol%29) page, I did not see an example of such usage...

Comment: It might be best to simply state what you are attempting to do by using words rather than symbols, especially since such operations are not commonly used.  If you were to define $\|$ as a binary operation as described in my link, then it follows that it is associative (but not commutative), at which point $a\|b\|c$ would be perfectly well defined, so if you wanted to take $a=31$, $b=33$ and $c=7$, then $a\|b\|c = 31337$.  Explicitly, in base 10 you would have $a\|b = a\cdot 10^{1+\lfloor\log_{10}b\rfloor} + b$

Comment: Just be sure to explain to the reader that you're working in base 10.